# Unable to move static IP address from one project to another in Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am unable to move a static IP address from one project to another.

```
 (eko-tourist)$ gcloud alpha compute addresses move static-ip-address     --target-project=cygeria     --new-name=Cygeria     --description='Cygeria IP address moved from eko-tourist project'     --region=us-west1
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.addresses.move) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Address move requests' and limit 'Address move requests per minute per region' of service 'compute.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:558156803518'.
```

I tried the provided command I got from google, and with the response is as above.